# CSS grey space appearing out of nowhere

Tags: html, css

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy44636b2a1tbu8/Screenshot%202014-09-05%2011.46.12.png?dl=0

I have a logo to the left and below is the header with links.  As you can see in the picture, in the top right there is a ton of grey space.

Here are the styles and the markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="identity">
                <a href="#"><img src="../i/logo.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navWrap">

            <ul id="nav">

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
position: relative;
width: 1120px;
margin: 0 auto; 
}
#header
{
height: 121px;
width: 1155px;  
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
#identity
{
z-index: 502;
float: left;
height: 85px;
width: 230px;
}
```

Why is this causing the grey space?  Let me know if you need anything else to debug the issue.

Comment: Do you have a `background-color` set on the header? Some browsers use gray as the default background color if there isn't one defined.

Comment: Is this posted anywhere that can be viewed?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this issue by adding `background-color: #fff;` to your container or wrapper rules.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set `background-color` in your header to whatever color the rest of your page is.

Here's a jsfiddle to see what is being styled: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/offshoresail/1sb2bs21/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the stylesheet you mention their might be another one overiding either the #wrapper #header #identity elements,
try firebug;

if it's not in css it's probably javascript that's changing the #identity styles

anyway adding

```
 #wrapper,#header,#identity{
 background-color:#fff !important }
```

or

```
 #wrapper,#header,#identity{
 background-color:none !important }
```

or

```
#wrapper,#header,#identity{
background-color:transparent !important }
```

will get the job done

Comment: I can't quite understand looking at your picture, could you paste your css sourcecode, from firebug or similar_ what about you #container ?

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting your DOM and styles in Chrome

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements

```
#header {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    background-image: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Picture of it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdd8jxbqw62l6wh/Screenshot%202014-09-05%2013.08.16.png?dl=0

Comment: I updated my answer with the CSS to fix your issue. This is the attribute you need to change:

background-image: transparent !important;